# Right inverses vs left inverse of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, inverse-function

> Consider a non-univalent analytic function $f: U \to \mathbb{C}$. Such a function does not have an inverse function, which would mean, as we recall , a function $g: f(U) \to U$ satisfying $g\left[ f(z) \right] = z$ for every $z$ in $U$ and $f(\left[ g(z) \right]=z$ for all $z$ in $f(U)$. What $f$ does have- and has in abundance are so called right inverse functions. This name is attached to any function $g: f(U) \to U$ enjoying the only latter property, $ f \left[ g(z) \right]=z$ for every $z$ in $U$
>
> Page-85, Bruce P. Palka

Could someone explain why a complex function has right inverses but not left inverses? Maybe an explanation with an explicit example would help.

Comment: you need a few more assumptions for the problem to be interesting - one wants holomorphic (continuous is enough) right inverses as otherwise trivially any function has right inverses from its image back to its domain; then you need $f$ to be locally univalent as otherwise you cannot get a continuous right inverse at a critical point (see $z^2$ at $0$) and then while under this assumption you always get a local right inverse, you need simple connectedness of the image in general to get a global inverse (see $e^z$)